# SQL: Select all values from one table in a join while not knowing all column names?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello there I wonder if the following is possible (in MySQL): There is a simple query joining two tables:

```
SELECT * FROM `contact_attending_appointment` AS tcon,`contact` AS tget WHERE tcon.appointment_id = 2 AND tget.id = tcon.contact_id;
```

This query will return the values of both tables - tcon and tget - joined together. However, I want only to have the columns of ONE table.

Basically in SQL you achieve it like this:

```
SELECT col_1,col_2,...,col_n FROM ...
```

Or you get all the columns with

```
SELECT * FROM ...
```

However I would like to have something like (as I do not know the columns of tget by their names)

```
SELECT [* from tget] FROM ...
```

Is there a general solution for this or is this not possible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
SELECT tget.* FROM contact AS tget ...
```

Comment: Thanks for refreshing my basic SQL skills, I hoped it would be that easy :-)

Comment: You are welcome. Also use `JOIN ON clauses` like @Gordon says.

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered by Rafa.  But you seem to be learning SQL.  The following is a better way of writing your query:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM `contact_attending_appointment` caa INNER JOIN
     `contact` c
     ON c.id = caa.contact_id 
WHERE caa.appointment_id = 2;
```

The important changes are:

1. Using proper ANSI join syntax, where the conditions are in the `on` clause rather than in the `where`.
2. Using table aliases that are abbreviations for the table name.  Someone looking at the query (even you in two months time) will find it easier to follow the logic.